# How to communicate with can with slcan?

Tags: can-bus

I have a target board where there is a `can` interface driven by `peak` drivers. On the host side I installed `can-utils`. I have a `can` cable which gets detected as `/dev/ttyUSBx` when I plugin.

The target board receives candata at 500000 baud rate

So on the host I executed,

```
sudo modprobe can
sudo modprobe can-raw
sudo modprobe slcan

sudo slcand -o -s8 -t hw -S 500000 /dev/ttyUSBx
sudo ip link set up slcan0
```

then I sent the candata from the host using:

```
cansend slcan0 600#ffffffffffffff
```

I can see the same using `candump slcan0` on the host.

But I don't receive anything on the target.

I tried the same with other cable in which I used (on the host)

```
sudo modprobe can
sudo ip link set can0 type can bitrate 500000 triple-sampling on
sudo ifconfig can0 up
```

then I was able to send can messages. If I try the same on the previous cable it throws error saying `Cannot find device "can0"`.

So How do I send through `slcan` interface?

Comment: Can you post a link to your USB-to-CAN cable?

Comment: There is no such thing as a USB-to-CAN cable, what you need is a USB-2-CAN controller, which is a chip. One option is USBtin(SB2), another option is the USB2CAN from innomaker (USB3).

Answer (score 4):

Your CAN bitrate is wrong. To setup 500kbit/s you need to invoke following commands:

```
sudo slcand -o -s6 -t hw -S 3000000 /dev/ttyUSBx
sudo ip link set up slcan0
```

`-s6` means CAN bitrate 500kbit/s, `-s8` means 1Mbit/s. `-S` parameter is used to setup serial speed to the USB-to-serial controller in the USB-to-CAN cable. The full CAN bitrate table for slcan can be found [here](http://elinux.org/Bringing_CAN_interface_up#SLCAN_based_Interfaces).

Comment: Why do we set the USB speed to 3Mbit/s ?

Comment: In our device an internal MCU is communicating with a host via a USB-to-serial IC at 3Mbit/s.

Comment: I found no explanation in [elinux bringing CAN I/F up](https://elinux.org/Bringing_CAN_interface_up) and thought there might be a "common sense" for that number.

Comment: I'll addan explanation. Thanks for heads up.

Answer (score 3):

according to [**eLinux - Bringing CAN I/F up**](https://elinux.org/Bringing_CAN_interface_up)

| ASCII Command | CAN Bitrate |
| --- | --- |
| s0 | 10 Kbit/s |
| s1 | 20 Kbit/s |
| s2 | 50 Kbit/s |
| s3 | 100 Kbit/s |
| s4 | 125 Kbit/s |
| s5 | 250 Kbit/s |
| s6 | 500 Kbit/s |
| s7 | 800 Kbit/s |
| s8 | 1000 Kbit/s |